# encoding of text data in NLP

Tags: python, nlp, preprocessing, similarity, text

I'm getting data using web scraping to create a dataset. I have a 'company' column that contains the names of the companies. I would like to encode this column but i don't know how to find the sentences that represent the same companies .

For example: "International Business Machines Corporation", "IBM", "IBM India Pvt.Ltd" reprsent the same company.

Any suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of problem is called [record linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage) (or sometimes entity matching or other variants). The task consists in finding among a list of strings representing entities (persons or organizations) those which represent the same actual entity.

There are two main approaches (which can be combined):

- String similarity matching methods. See for example [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/85647/64377) or [this one](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/63325/64377). Note that in case the list of companies is large, there can also be an efficiency issue: see this [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/54570/64377).
- Databases or third-party resources. See for example [this related question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/56406/64377).